# Scripted jenkins pipeline slackSend is not displaying vertical color line

Tags: jenkins, groovy, slack

In Jenkins Scripted (groovy) pipeline, I have below code line

```
slackSend channel: '#Regression-Testing-Result', 
color: (currentBuild.result.equals("SUCCESS")) ? "good" : "danger",
message: (currentBuild.result.equals("SUCCESS")) ? "Tests passed" : "Tests failed"
```

**Issue :**
Tests passed or Tests failed message is printed in slack channel (Regression-Testing-Result) but the colored vertical line is not printed (vertical green line for success, vertical red line for failure)

**Jenkins version                  :  2.319.3**

**Slack Upload Plugin version used : 1.7**

Answer (score 0):

Implement the slack notification this way:

```
 post {
        always {
            echo 'Slack Notification'
            slackSend channel: '#Regression-Testing-Result',
            color: COLOR_MAP[currentBuild.currentResult],
            message: "*${currentBuild.currentResult}:* Job ${env.JOB_NAME} "
        }
    }
```

ADD the below snippet above your pipeline:

```
def COLOR_MAP = [
    'SUCCESS': 'good',
    'FAILURE': 'danger'
]
pipeline{

}
```